# Context menu in Chrome extension creating undisired replica menus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

Here's my code that creates the right-click menu:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "copy '%s' to clipboard", 
    contexts: ["selection"], 
    onclick: function(info) { 
        wordObject[wordObject.length] = {
            word: info.selectionText,
            definition: " 'add definition' "
        };
        runArray();
        chrome.storage.sync.set({"myValue": wordObject});
    }
});
```

The problem is that every time I refresh the page another selection under my menu is created.

**EDIT**

I kind of fixed it, but it requires refreshing the page every time I click. Any way around this?

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "copy '%s' to clipboard", 
    contexts: ["selection"], 
    onclick: function(info) { 
        wordObject[wordObject.length] = {
            word: info.selectionText,
            definition: " 'add definition' "
        };
        runArray();
        chrome.storage.sync.set({"myValue": wordObject});
        chrome.contextMenus.removeAll();
        location.reload(); // Refreshes page! Probably not good
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to create a menu item, you should make a single call to `contextMenus.create`. Generally, you only want to create menu items once, at the time your extension is initialized. You seem to be calling `contextMenus.create` each time you load a web page. Don't do that.

You probably have your call to `contextMenus.create` inside some function that runs with each page load. Take it out of that function and place it somewhere that it will only run once, ever, for the loaded lifetime of the extension. For example, running `contextMenus.create` inside a background script, not inside any function, should be sufficient.

Of course, make sure wherever you move your call to `contextMenus.create`, the callback function still keeps `wordObject` and `runArray` in scope.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @apsillers' answer, here is an example of creating a context menu item on installation for a non-persistent extension (one that uses a Page Action instead of a Browser Action), taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26246735/461834):

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: 'My menu',
        id: 'menu1', // you'll use this in the handler function to identify this context menu item
        contexts: ['all'],
    });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId === "menu1") { // here's where you'll need the ID
        // do something
    }
});
```