# Adding context menu item on a non-persistent background script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am adding a context menu item from a **non-persistent** background script using:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: 'Get Code',
  id: 'myUniqueIdForThisExtension123',
  contexts: ['all'],
  onclick: onClickHandler
});

function onClickHandler() {}
```

The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus) simply states:

> The unique ID to assign to this item. Mandatory for event pages. Cannot be the same as another ID for this extension.

So I added a unique ID, but I still cannot make it work. Nothing new inserted on the context menu.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You are saying you've got a non-persistent background page, so you should have a `manifest.json` file that looks like this:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "My extension",
    "description": "My description",
    "version": "1",
    
    "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": [
            "/background.js"
        ] 
    }
}
```

Now, since you've got a non-persistent background page, you have to use the right listeners to "wake it up" when you need to use the context menu.

Quoting from the [official documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20140302025634/https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) (NOTE: this link points to an archived copy of the documentation from 2014 and is outdated):

> Best practices when using event pages:
>
> [...]
>
> 7. If you're using the context menus API, pass a string id parameter to `contextMenus.create`, and use the **[`contextMenus.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked) callback instead of an `onclick`** parameter to `contextMenus.create`.

So, simply, your error is using the `onclick` parameter instead of the `contextMenus.onClicked.addListener()` method in your `background.js`.

### Solution

I already said that you should use the `onClicked` event, but I would like to add that, referring to [x a's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27251743/3889449):

> **You should register a context menu via `contextMenus.create` in the event handler of [`runtime.onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled)**, as these context menu registrations persist anyway.

So simply, given that once created the context menus persist in your extension, it's best practice to only define them a single time: when your extension is installed (or updated), and add the listener each time the background page is loaded.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: 'My menu',
        id: 'menu1', // you'll use this in the handler function to identify this context menu item
        contexts: ['all'],
    });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId === "menu1") { // here's where you'll need the ID
        // do something
    }
});
```

That's what you need to create a context menu in an event page, as shown in the **[documentation page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus)** of the `chrome.contextMenus` API.

Comment: Hi, the background script is non-persistent, so `"background": { "persistent": false, scripts: [] }`

Comment: @MarcoBonelli in my comment I said background page and your edit reflects this, but I should have said event page, since it's non-persistent. You might want to re-edit your most recent edit to change background page to event page.

Comment: @BrianOnn well, event pages are a subcategory of background pages, that's not wrong to call it like so. By the way for these minor edits feel free to apply them by your own.

Answer (score 9):

Ammending what Marco Bonelli [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26246735/2439834):

If you want to use an *event page* or a *non-persistent background page*, as you call it, you should register a context menu via `contextMenus.create` in the event handler of `runtime.onInstalled`, as these context menu registrations ”persist“ anyway.

You have to add the listener-function for the `contextMenus.onClicked` event every time the *event page* gets reloaded, though, as the registration of your *wish* to listen on that event persists, while the *handler* callback itself does *not*.

So to do it right™, register your context-menu-to-be from `runtime.onInstalled`, but set the event handler callback itself using `contextMenus.onClicked.addListener` from top level or other code, that is guaranteed to be executed each time the *event page* loads.<sup>[[1](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)]</sup>

Comment: @Marco you should amend your answer to at least point to this.

Comment: @Xan I was actually doing it (and I did rn), thanks.