# chrome.contextMenus `onclick` doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add a context menu item to a chrome app and it's not showing up at all. Everything I've read seems to indicate that I'm doing the right thing here, but evidently I'm not.

background.js:

```
var clickHandler = function(e) {
  console.log('testing testing');
}
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title": "Click Me",
  "contexts": ["page", "selection", "image", "link"],
  "onclick" : clickHandler
});
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Test",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "3.2.3",
    "kiosk_enabled": true,
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon_128.png",
        "16": "icon_16.png"
    },
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
            "persistent": false
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "http://*/", "https://*/", "webview", "storage", "power", "alwaysOnTopWindows", "idle", "contextMenus"
    ]
}
```

There are no errors being logged or anything like that. The item simply does not show up. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed a [small note](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#property-createProperties-onclick) in the `contextMenu` documentation:

> function  (optional) `onclick`
>   A function that will be called back when the menu item is clicked. Event pages cannot use this; instead, they should register a listener for `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked`

You do have an [Event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) (`"persistent": false`), so it applies to you.

Chrome unloads the page, and the reference to `clickHandler` can get lost. On the contrary, Event page mechanism ensures that if you registered an event with `addListener` the page will be loaded again, `addListener` applied again and then your listener executed.

So:

```
var clickHandler = function(e) {
  console.log('testing testing');
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title": "Click Me",
  "contexts": ["page", "selection", "image", "link"]
});

// Must be synchronously called on event page load,
//   for instance in the top level code
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(clickHandler);
```

Comment: Just to add to this, the API now requires an id to be passed into the create function. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245888/adding-context-menu-item-on-a-non-persistent-background-script