# function(event) within an Opera context-menu extension

Tags: javascript, syntax, opera

I am trying to write a simple extension for Opera. It adds a "Search Google for image" when you right-click on an image, just like in Chrome. Similar extensions already exist, but this is for the sake of learning.

My first attempt used onClick, which is not the correct way. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245888/adding-context-menu-item-on-a-non-persistent-background-script) to rewrite my bg.js file. It now looks like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: "Search Google for image",
        id: "gsearch",
        contexts: ["image"]
    });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId === "gsearch") {
        function(event) {
            chrome.tabs.create({
                url: "https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=" + encodeURIComponent(event.srcUrl);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

When I load the extension, Opera complains about line 11 where `function(event) {` causes the error message `Unexpected token (`. I am obviously **missing something regarding syntax** here, and would appreciate your expertise.

Comment: Function declarations inside if-blocks are invalid in ES5, and yours doesn't even have a name (making it twice as invalid). What is that function supposed to do at all? Drop it.

Comment: Thank you. Without that function, how do I pass `event` to `encodeURIComponent`?

Comment: What is `event` supposed to be at all? Isn't it the same as `info`?

Comment: Indeed. I did not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function cannot be declared inside an `if` block. Furthermore, `info` can be passed to `encodeURIComponent`. The following code works:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: "Search Google for image",
        id: "gsearch",
        contexts: ["image"]
    });
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId === "gsearch") {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: "https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=" + encodeURIComponent(info.srcUrl)
        });
    }
});
```

Thank you Bergi.